# Installing Tensorflow on OSX - clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: xcode, macos, tensorflow, clang, bazel

I am trying to install Tensorflow for OSX (Mojave 10.14.3) from source and received the following error when running `bazel build --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package` in the terminal as described in https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_PyModule_AddIntConstant", referenced from:
      _PyInit__api_implementation in api_implementation.o
  "_PyModule_Create2", referenced from:
      _PyInit__api_implementation in api_implementation.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
```

According to similar (but not equal) posts on stackoverflow, it seems to have something to do with Xcode.

I have already tried reinstalling the Xcode command line tools and updating Xcode itself. But to no avail. Also, there is no way for me to change something in the code.
I appreciate Your help!

Comment: Made a Github issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/26589

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved in the `Latest Versions` of `Bazel`.

The Code which has fixed this issue is shown below:

```
#def system_specific_test_config(env): Deleted This Line
  """Add default test flags required for TF tests to bazelrc."""
def system_specific_config(env): #Added this Line
  """Add default build and test flags required for TF tests to bazelrc."""
  write_to_bazelrc('test --flaky_test_attempts=3')
  write_to_bazelrc('test --test_size_filters=small,medium')
  write_to_bazelrc(
@@ -1520,6 +1520,10 @@ def system_specific_test_config(env):
  elif is_macos():
    write_to_bazelrc('test --test_tag_filters=-gpu,-nomac,-no_mac')
    write_to_bazelrc('test --build_tag_filters=-gpu,-nomac,-no_mac')
    # TODO(pcloudy): Remove BAZEL_USE_CPP_ONLY_TOOLCHAIN after Bazel is upgraded
    # to 0.24.0.
    # For working around https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/7607
    write_to_bazelrc('build --action_env=BAZEL_USE_CPP_ONLY_TOOLCHAIN=1')
  elif is_linux():
    if env.get('TF_NEED_CUDA', None) == '1':
      write_to_bazelrc('test --test_tag_filters=-no_gpu')
@@ -1747,7 +1751,7 @@ def main():
    create_android_ndk_rule(environ_cp)
    create_android_sdk_rule(environ_cp)

  #system_specific_test_config(os.environ) #Deleted this Line
  system_specific_config(os.environ) #Added this Line

  if get_var(
      environ_cp, 'TF_CONFIGURE_APPLE_BAZEL_RULES',
```

For more information, refer [Link1](https://github.com/testkevinbonz/tensorflow/commit/7bd86377dedaf459d22b68363a0a2d4580180379) and [Link2](https://github.com/emusand/bazel/commit/5fc248e48b24e4b43bf4e486912551412b8c3214).